# Selenium get(url) showing wrong page

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to web scrape a dynamically loaded page with Selenium. I can copy and paste the below url into a normal Chrome browser and it works perfectly fine but when I use selenium, it return the wrong page of horse races for a different day. It seems to work the first time you run the code but retains some sort of memory and you cannot run it again with a different date as it just returns the original date?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.tab.com.au/racing/meetings/2021-06-11"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('xxxxxxxx')

driver.get(url)
```

Has anyone every come across something like this with Selenium?

Comment: even if I use Chrome I can see only `tab.com.au is unavailable from your location` - so I can't even test this page to see what can be the problem.

Comment: Apologies, you probably need to be in Australia for it to work. Or maybe VPN?